# how to work data-toggle button in another that work in header.php include that file in another file button-toggle not work

Tags: php

This is data-toggle code in header.php but not work when include that file in anther file

```
<ul class="user-menu">
                <li class="dropdown pull-right">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><svg class="glyph stroked male-user"><use xlink:href="#stroked-male-user"></use></svg> User <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><svg class="glyph stroked male-user"><use xlink:href="#stroked-male-user"></use></svg> Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><svg class="glyph stroked gear"><use xlink:href="#stroked-gear"></use></svg> Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><svg class="glyph stroked cancel"><use xlink:href="#stroked-cancel"></use></svg> Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add more information and code to help us identify the problem.

Comment: that data-toggle html code in header.php file when  I incldude that file in another file that time data-toggle bellow dropdown list not working what should I do for it will work correctly